# calculate Count and Sum from two different table with group by without using inner query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table first A having `column id,phone_number,refer_amount`

and second B having column `phone_number,transaction_amount`

now i want `sum()` of refer_amount and transaction_amount and `count()` of phone_number from both table using group by phone_number without using inner query

Table A

```
phone_number    refer_amount
123             50
456             80
789             90
123             90
123             80
123             20
456             20
456             79
456             49
123             49
```

Table B

```
phone_number     transaction_amount
123              50
123              51
123              79
456              22
456              11
456              78
456              66
456              88
456              88
456              66
789              66
789              23
789              78
789              46
```

i have tried following query but it gives me wrong output:

```
SELECT a.phone_number,COUNT(a.phone_number) AS refer_count,SUM(a.refer_amount) AS refer_amount,b.phone_number,COUNT(b.phone_number) AS toal_count,SUM(b.transaction_amount) AS transaction_amount FROM dbo.A AS a,dbo.B AS b WHERE a.phone_number=b.phone_number GROUP BY a.phone_number,b.phone_number
```

output (wrong):

```
phone_number  refer_count  refer_amount  phone_number  transaction_count  transaction_amount
123           15           867           123           15                 900
456           28           1596          456           28                 1676
789           5            450           789           5                  291
```

output (That I want):

```
phone_number  refer_count  refer_amount  phone_number  transaction_count  transaction_amount
123           5            289           123           3                  180
456           4            228           456           7                  419
789           1            90            789           5                  291
```

Comment: Is there any relationship between these two tables?

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the aggregations on the `B` table in a separate subquery, and then join to it:

```
SELECT
    a.phone_number,
    COUNT(a.phone_number) AS a_cnt,
    SUM(a.refer_amount)   AS a_sum,
    COALESCE(b.b_cnt, 0)  AS b_cnt,
    COALESCE(b.b_sum, 0)  AS b_sum
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        phone_number,
        COUNT(*) AS b_cnt,
        SUM(transaction_amount) AS b_sum
    FROM B
    GROUP BY phone_number
) b
    ON a.phone_number = b.phone_number;
```

One major potential issue with your current approach is that the join could result in duplicate counting, as a given `phone_number` record in the `A` table gets replicated due to the join.

Speaking of joins, note that above I use an explicit join, rather than the implicit one you were using.  In general, you should not put commas into the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Tim there is no relationship between this two table so i can not appy left join

Comment: @PrashantSonar Your current query implies otherwise: `where a.phone_number=b.phone_number` ... if there really is no relationship between the two tables, then in general we can't write a query on both tables at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This can help. You don't need sum(b.phone_number) when checking for a.phone_number = b.phone_number. Distinct is needed for phone number as there are two columns to consider.

For group by, anything not in aggregate function needs to be in group by function.

```
select a.phone_number, count(distinct a.phone_number), sum(a.refer_amount),
  sum (b.transaction_amount) 
  from A as a, B as b 
where a.phone_number=b.phone_number 
group by a.phone_number
```